# Text alignment in greek is not working

Tags: xetex, greek

I am trying to align my text in XeLaTeX, but some words seem to fall out of place. The compiled text looks like this 
[image]

I have read some similar questions and I have already tried the  following:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justify
\justifying
\centerline
\center
```

None of the above commands worked. How can I fix this? The code in XeLaTeX is the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec,xgreek,polyglossia}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliography}



\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman} 

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}

\title{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ntua.jpg} \\ \\ \newline \textbf{Σκιαγράφημα Εργασίας}

\date{Απρίλιος 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Περίληψη}

Στα πλαίσια της εργασίας θα διερευνηθούν ποικίλες μέθοδοι, με τις οποίες μπορεί να ανιχνευθεί η κόπωση ενός γιατρού, νοσοκόμου ή άλλου εργαζομένου σε τομείς της Υγείας και ο τρόπος αξιοποίησης των παραπάνω δεδομένων για την αποφυγή υπερκόπωσης και ιατρικών λαθών. Αφορμή για την παραπάνω έρευνα υπήρξε η έξαρση του ιού SARS-CoV-2, ο οποίος προκαλεί την ασθένεια Covid-19. Αποτέλεσμα της έξαρσης αυτής υπήρξε η μεγάλη καταπόνηση των παγκόσμιων συστημάτων υγείας και οι υπερωρίες που αναγκάστηκαν να τελέσουν οι εργαζόμενοι στους τομείς της υγείας. Στόχος της εργασίας αυτής είναι η ανάπτυξη εφαρμογής κινητού τηλεφώνου, η οποία θα ανιχνεύει την κόπωση των εργαζομένων στον τομέα της Υγείας, θα λαμβάνει την προσωπική τους εκτίμηση σχετικά με τη αίσθηση της κόπωσης που έχουν και θα τους ενημερώνει για την ακρίβεια της εκτίμησης τους. Οι παραπάνω μετρήσεις αποσκοπούν, στην εύκολη και γρήγορη ενημέρωση του εργαζομένου, σχετικά με την κατάσταση της πνευματικής και σωματικής κόπωσης τους και η εξαγωγή συμπερασμάτων για την υπερεκτίμηση ή υποεκτίμηση της κατάστασης τους.\newline \newline 

\textbf{Λέξεις Κλειδιά: } Εργαζόμενοι,Υγεία,Κόπωση,Εφαρμογή,Έξυπνο τηλέφωνο

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...It is helpful if you provide `MWE` of your code...

Comment: @MadyYuvi thanks for the input, I edited to provide MWE of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not load `xgreek`, which is not for XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Also, it appears that your main language is Greek, rather than English.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,polyglossia}



\setmainfont{Times New Roman} 

\setmainlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}

\title{Σκιαγράφημα Εργασίας}

\date{Απρίλιος 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Περίληψη}

Στα πλαίσια της εργασίας θα διερευνηθούν ποικίλες μέθοδοι, με τις οποίες 
μπορεί να ανιχνευθεί η κόπωση ενός γιατρού, νοσοκόμου ή άλλου εργαζομένου 
σε τομείς της Υγείας και ο τρόπος αξιοποίησης των παραπάνω δεδομένων για 
την αποφυγή υπερκόπωσης και ιατρικών λαθών. Αφορμή για την παραπάνω έρευνα 
υπήρξε η έξαρση του ιού SARS-CoV-2, ο οποίος προκαλεί την ασθένεια Covid-19. 
Αποτέλεσμα της έξαρσης αυτής υπήρξε η μεγάλη καταπόνηση των παγκόσμιων συστημάτων 
υγείας και οι υπερωρίες που αναγκάστηκαν να τελέσουν οι εργαζόμενοι στους τομείς 
της υγείας. Στόχος της εργασίας αυτής είναι η ανάπτυξη εφαρμογής κινητού τηλεφώνου, 
η οποία θα ανιχνεύει την κόπωση των εργαζομένων στον τομέα της Υγείας, θα λαμβάνει 
την προσωπική τους εκτίμηση σχετικά με τη αίσθηση της κόπωσης που έχουν και θα τους 
ενημερώνει για την ακρίβεια της εκτίμησης τους. Οι παραπάνω μετρήσεις αποσκοπούν, 
στην εύκολη και γρήγορη ενημέρωση του εργαζομένου, σχετικά με την κατάσταση της 
πνευματικής και σωματικής κόπωσης τους και η εξαγωγή συμπερασμάτων για την 
υπερεκτίμηση ή υποεκτίμηση της κατάστασης τους.

\textbf{Λέξεις Κλειδιά:} Εργαζόμενοι,Υγεία,Κόπωση,Εφαρμογή,Έξυπνο τηλέφωνο

\end{document}
```

[image]

Add also the packages you need. But *don't* use `\newline`.

Comment: thanks for the help, it worked perfectly